# Nested Maven modules not fully represented in Project when imported into IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, module

I have a large repository containing a Maven project that is partitioned into many modules and sub modules.

Something like:

```
root
-area1
--A
---api
---impl
--B
---api
---impl
--C
---api
---impl
-area2
--X
---api
---impl
--Y
---api
---impl
--Z
---api
---impl
```

This is of course simplified.
area1, area2 and their submodules are defined as pom type Maven projects where api and impl are defined as jaras.

I'm trying to add a new Maven module to the root called `subset` (same level as area1, area2 and area3) that will reference only part of the existing modules so I could load only that subset module into IntelliJ to save system resources and also configure additional tooling that I have for the subset project.

The end goal is to create multiple such subset projects that use the same basic/shared modules in the same repository (Monorepo).

I defined the subset project pom to be something like:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>root.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>root.artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<groupId>subset.group</groupId>
<artifactId>subset.artifact</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>../area1/A</module>
    <module>../area1/B</module>
    <module>../area2/Z</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <root-basedir>${basedir}/..</root-basedir>
</properties>
```

The problem is that when I import the subset Maven project into an empty IntelliJ (2020.3.4) Maven works just fine (all of the dependencies and module structure are there) however when I look at the `Project` structure I see:

```
subset
area1
-api
-api
-impl
-impl
area2
-api
-impl
```

- It seems that IntelliJ has cut the module names out (A, B and Z) and just added the leaves (api and impl - all of them from all 3 modules)
- If I switch to `Project Files` view I see the files in the expected structure:

```
subset
area1
-A
--api
--impl
-B
--api
--impl
area2
-Z
--api
--impl
```

If I look at the `Project Structure` (File->Project Structure) I can see that the modules are imported just fine, it seems to be purely a display issue.

Any idea on how to make the `Project` and `Project Files` reflect the same structure? (without missing the pom grouping modules A,B and Z along the way)

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Try updating the IDE to 2021.3. Does it help?

Comment: This looks odd: `../area1/A`...

Comment: @khmarbaise why does it look odd? - it's just a reference to a pom on the file system. Iv'e used this before many times.

Comment: It shows that your directory structure is not represented by your pom structure or vice versa...which is usually a architectural issue...This is also shows that you don't follow best practice to have a parent pom in the directory `area1` etc. ...Using something many times doesn't means it's a good or best practice...

Comment: @khmarbaise just to be clear, area1 has a parent pom (root) and contains mainly modules. The root pom structure is just fine - all the projects are visible as expected.
The subset pom is just aggregating partial "areas" that are all under the root and when I'm looking at File->Project Structure I can see that the modules aggregated by the subset pom are all there in the structure I expected, it's just the UI (Project pane) that isn't reflecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the reason for all of this is the artifact ids in my pom files.

It seems that IntelliJ tries to match parent artifact ids with the module artifact id and bunch them together. When that happens IntelliJ duplicates (just visually in the project pane) all of the sub-modules along side the actual module (as long as they all have the prefix parent in the artifact id) - this happens recursively which can be very annoying and makes things seem very cluttered in large projects that run deep module trees.

The solution is probably not to use an artifact id like ParentID.ModuleID.SubmoduleID but instead use just SubmoduleID for the sub module, ModuleID for the module and ParentID for the parent (meaning no dotting in the ID)